# Vuejs component remove on v-for

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I created a Vuejs component like this:

```html
<template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
            <label>Product</label>
            <select class="form-control custom-select" name="product_id[]" @change="getBrand" required>
                <option></option>
                <option v-for="product in myProducts" :value="product.id">{{ product.name }}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
            <label>Brand</label>
            <select class="form-control custom-select" name="brand_id[]" @change="getItem" required>
                <option></option>
                <option v-for="brand in filteredBrand" :value="brand.id">{{ brand.name }}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
            <label>Item</label>
            <select class="form-control custom-select" name="item_id[]" required>
                <option></option>
                <option v-for="item in filteredItem" :value="item.id">{{ item.name }}</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
            <label>Price</label>
            <input type="text" name="buy_price[]" class="form-control" value="0" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
            <label>Quantity</label>
            <input type="text" name="quantity[]" class="form-control" value="0" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <div class="form-group form-group-default required">
            <label>Cost</label>
            <input type="text" name="cost[]" class="form-control" value="0.75" required>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <a href="" class="btn btn-success input-sm mr-2" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add new" @click.prevent="$emit('add')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            <a href="" class="btn btn-danger input-sm" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add new" @click.prevent="$emit('remove')"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
        </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['products', 'brands', 'items'],
        data: function () {
        return {
          myProducts: this.products,
          myBrands: this.brands,
          myItems: this.items,
          filteredBrand: null,
          filteredItem: null
        }
    },
    methods:{
            getBrand(e){
                this.filteredBrand = this.myBrands.filter(brand => brand.product_id == e.currentTarget.value);
            },
            getItem(e){
                this.filteredItem = this.myItems.filter(item => item.brand_id == e.currentTarget.value);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

And added the component to a page like this:

```
<product v-for="(detail, index) in details" :key="index" :products="{{ $products }}" :brands="{{ $brands }}" :items="{{ $items }}" @add="addItem" @remove="removeItem(index)">
```

And here is my main page script:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myApp = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data:{
            details: [{}],
        },
        methods: {
            addItem(){
                this.details.push({});
            },
            removeItem(index){
                if (this.details.length > 1) {
                    this.details.splice(index, 1);
                }
            },
        }
    });
</script>
```

Everything works fine but `removeItem` method.

When I click on remove button beside each instance of component it will remove the last one, not the one I clicked.

I don't know what is the problem.

This is an online example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/great-elbakyan-d0xt5?file=/index.html:0-2914

Comment: removeItem parameter index got undefined

Comment: A small note that may not actually solve your issue but you must consider, when adding/removing items from the list, avoid using index as key for the component since this will cause unexpected behavior. Instead, using a unique key such as ID of the details if exists of a random id.

Comment: update the line 10 on sandbox with @remove="removeItem(index)" //index is missing

Comment: @MohamedRaza I just missed that part, thanks. but the result is the same.

Comment: you can do the same work by storing this array into a localstorage. that could work properly

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-danger input-sm" data-tooltip="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add new" @click.prevent="$emit('remove', index)"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></a>
```

```
props: ['products', 'brands', 'items', 'index'],
```

```
<product v-for="(detail, index) in details" :key="index" :index="index" :products="{{ $products }}" :brands="{{ $brands }}" :items="{{ $items }}" @add="addItem" @remove="removeItem">
```

Comment: Thank you but it is not working. (exactly the same result)